# How do I change ∃x, ∀y, P(x, y) into ∃y, ∃x, P(x, y)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm very confused as to how to even begin, any explanation or help would be really appreciated. I understand Universal and Existential Quantifiers but the actual process of proving it is what confuses me.

Comment: This is actually not always true; it depends on whether there are any values of $y$ in existence.

Comment: In order "to prove this in a step-wise manner" you have to specify the *proof system* you are workink with : *Natural Deduction*, axioms and rules, ...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

- Imagine a huge table/matrix with entries in $p_{x,y} \in \{0,1\}$,
  where $x$ determines the row and $y$ determines the column, for example
  $$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
    &y_1&y_2&y_3\\\hline
    x_1&p_{x_1,y_1}&p_{x_1,y_2}&p_{x_1,y_3} \\
    x_2&p_{x_2,y_1}&p_{x_2,y_2}&p_{x_2,y_3} \\
    x_3&p_{x_3,y_1}&p_{x_3,y_2}&p_{x_3,y_3}
    \end{array}$$
- Suppose that $$P(x,y) \iff p_{x,y} = 1,$$ then
  $\exists x.\ \forall y.\ P(x,y)$ says
  \begin{align}
    &\exists x &&\text{ there exists a row such that }\\
    &\forall y &&\text{ for all columns }\\
    &P(x,y)    && \text{ we have }p_{x,y} = 1.
    \end{align}
- On the other hand $\exists y.\ \exists x.\ P(x,y)$ says
  \begin{align}
    &\exists y &&\text{ there exists a column such that }\\
    &\exists x &&\text{ there exists a row where }\\
    &P(x,y)    && \text{ we have }p_{x,y} = 1.
    \end{align}
- In other words, given there exists a row full of $1$'s, does a column that contains at least one value $1$ have to exist?
- Observe that for the theorem to work we need an assumption that there is at least one column.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I understand what the question is actually asking of me better. However, I need to be able to prove this in a step-wise manner.  Sorry if my question was phrased a little to vaguely, I only just started learning discrete mathematics.

Comment: @JohnS. I suspected this is the case and intentionally provided that particular hint. Don't forget that it is _you_ who has to learn to realize your thoughts in the language of math, which is the actual challenge of this problem.

Comment: I understand your point, thanks for taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You are given $\exists x\ \forall y\ P(x, y)$. So, writing this in words, we can say that there exists a special value of $x$ such that for all $y$ (no matter what $y$ is chosen), $P(x, y)$ is always going to be true. So lets choose this special value of $x$ and call it $x_0$. Now, no matter what $y$ value you choose, $P(x_0, y)$ is always going to be true. Can you finish the argument from there?